# Borders of overlapping circles

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, geometry

Given the coordinates of several points on a plane, and the radius of a circle surrounding each point, draw polygons representing the circles and the edges where the circles meet. Straight edges will always fall along [circle-circle intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) lines, but might not follow the full length of these lines.

<s>Per [mbomb007](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34718/mbomb007)'s suggestion, imagine the behavior of 2D soap bubbles.</s> That's technically wrong, because soap bubbles would [always meet at 120° angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%27s_laws) to minimize energy, while these circles may meet at any angle.

<s>**This is a Voronoi diagram, minus a defined area plane.** Thanks [Andreas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52361/andreas).</s> This is actually a generalization of a Voronoi diagram called a [power diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_diagram).

### Examples

For example, given two points and two radii, the output might look like this:

[image]

Add another point and radius and the output might look like this:

[image]

### Input

You can structure the input however you wish. Please post results with the following inputs.

**Test 1**

- x: 10, y: 10, r: 10
- x: 25, y: 12, r: 8

**Test 2**

- x: 8, y: 10, r: 6
- x: 20, y: 8, r: 4
- x: 18, y: 20, r: 12

### Output

Output should be graphical and should include polygon borders, but nothing else is required. Points and intersections do not need to be represented like they are in the examples.

### Constraints

- No point will exist within the radius of another circle.
- Standard codegolf rules.
- No answers with [loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) will be accepted, but feel free to have fun with it.

Comment: What do the edges in Fig. 2 radiate outwards from a point which is not a point of intersection?  Shouldn't the edges be from intersection point to intersection point?  My understanding is that the polygon in Fig. 2 should be a triangle.

Comment: I was assuming he was using the [Radical Center](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadicalCenter.html), which is the point of intersection of their pairwise [radical lines](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html).

Comment: I find my intentions difficult to articulate. Imagine that the circles are all slowly expanding from their points. A circle will stop this expansion on an edge when it encounters another circle. The circle's unencumbered edges will continue to expand until they reach their specified radius. I don't have a strong background in geometry or math, so I apologize for perhaps not speaking accurately. Please feel free to add clarification to the question if you get my meaning.

Comment: Nate, the algorithm in your last comment is not [well-defined](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WellDefined.html): we don't know what rate each circle is expanding at, so we don't know where the line is. If you do mean the radical center (see the links in @Neil 's comment), I suggest you [edit] the question to indicate as much.

Comment: Nate, Finding the points of intersection of circles is clear.  How do you define the point in Fig. 2 where the three line segments meet?   How do you define (or at least describe) the line segments themselves?  The line segment in Fig. 1 is simply the line segment between the two points of intersection.

Comment: You should change the title to mention bubbles. These look like 2D bubbles.

Comment: I appreciate the input and I've added more detail at the top. I hope that the bit about circle-circle intersection lines will provide enough clarification.

Comment: Your test2 does not match the picture.

Comment: You're asking for the Voronoi tessellation of a plane given a set of points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, nor does the first. They are not intended to match.

Comment: In a Voronoi diagram, "for each seed [point] there is a corresponding region consisting of all points closer to that seed than to any other".  That is clearly not the case for Figure 2.

Comment: @Andreas DavidC is right, this would be a Voronoi diagram only if all circles were of equal radius

Comment: This problem is asking for a [power diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_diagram) of the circles.

Comment: Is it possible that the three line segments in Fig. 2 intersect at the centroid of the polygon with the circle centers as vertices?

Comment: @DavidC No, Neil is correct that they intersect at the radical center.

Comment: Anders, Ok, Now I understand.

Comment: Is it acceptable to produce the areas in different colours, not the border lines? The lines would only be implied by a colour change

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Python 2, <s>473</s> 355 bytes

```py
L=input()
m=min
a,b,c,d=eval('m(%s-r for u,v,r in L),'*4%('u','v','-u','-v'))
e=(-c-a)/499.
H=lambda x,y:x*x+y*y
I=500
J=int(2-(d+b)/e)
print'P2',I,J,255
i=I*J
P=lambda(u,v,r):H(c+i%I*e+u,b+i/I*e-v)-r*r
while i:i-=1;p,k=m((P(k)/[1,k[2]][P(k)>0],k)for k in L);u,v,r=k;print int(255*m(1,[m([-p/r]+[(P(l)-p)/H(u-l[0],v-l[1])**.5for l in L-{k}]),p][p>0]/2/e))
```

This reads a set of circles as `(x,y,r)` tuples on stdin, and outputs an image in PGM format to stdout.  It works roughly by computing a distance function of the diagram at each pixel, and shading each pixel less than one pixel away proportionally to its distance.

```
{(10,10,10),(25,12,8)}
```

[image: output 1]

```
{(8,10,6),(20,8,4),(18,20,12)}
```

[image: output 2]

```
{(6, 63, 4), (16, 88, 9), (64, 94, 11), (97, 96, 3), (23, 32, 13), (54, 14, 7), (41, 81, 3), (7, 7, 4), (77, 18, 8), (98, 55, 4), (2, 56, 7), (62, 18, 5), (13, 74, 2), (33, 56, 12), (49, 48, 4), (6, 76, 2), (82, 70, 9), (21, 71, 2), (27, 5, 10), (3, 32, 6), (70, 62, 6), (74, 46, 4), (21, 60, 7), (18, 47, 7), (94, 2, 4), (39, 97, 7), (62, 63, 2), (87, 29, 8), (19, 17, 4), (61, 23, 2), (73, 1, 8), (40, 17, 13), (99, 41, 4), (81, 57, 7), (1, 68, 5), (38, 3, 4), (46, 36, 9), (4, 39, 2), (73, 77, 3), (93, 19, 10), (67, 42, 3), (96, 65, 2), (2, 16, 3), (28, 92, 3), (54, 58, 2), (39, 86, 5), (84, 82, 5), (79, 43, 4), (5, 47, 1), (34, 41, 8), (65, 5, 2), (9, 44, 3), (53, 3, 6), (1, 12, 1), (81, 95, 7), (74, 31, 2), (63, 61, 1), (35, 72, 1), (44, 71, 2), (57, 35, 5), (46, 65, 6), (57, 45, 4), (93, 94, 1), (99, 81, 13), (13, 58, 4), (68, 32, 6), (11, 2, 6), (52, 98, 7), (51, 25, 5), (84, 2, 2), (44, 92, 3), (23, 72, 2), (32, 99, 7), (13, 19, 3), (97, 29, 8), (58, 80, 3), (67, 82, 5), (59, 60, 3), (86, 87, 5), (29, 73, 2), (5, 93, 4), (42, 74, 1), (75, 85, 8), (91, 53, 5), (23, 82, 4), (19, 97, 8), (51, 88, 3), (67, 12, 6), (60, 53, 1), (66, 72, 2), (57, 64, 2), (66, 49, 2), (44, 0, 4), (11, 69, 1), (93, 60, 5), (56, 50, 3), (19, 68, 3), (64, 75, 3), (6, 17, 2), (82, 5, 2)}
```

[image: output 3]

Here the distance function has been divided by 32 to make it visible:

```
{(7, 9, 7), (1, 3, 2), (4, 0, 4), (9, 2, 4), (0, 8, 5)}
```

[image: distance function demo]

Comment: save at the top: `exec"%s=m%s(%s for u,v,r in L);"*4%('a','in','u-r','b','ax','v-r','c','in','u+r','d','ax','v+r')`

Answer (score 9):

**C# ~2746**

This is a solution in C#. Probably far from optimal but C# wont win this anyway. Just wanted myself to prove that i can do it.

Input via commandline by specifying the values seperated with a space
in the order x y r
Output is a file 'l.bmp' within the executing directory.

Program accepts any ammount of circles.

Test 1 : 10 10 10 25 12 8

Test 2 : 8 10 6 20 8 4 18 20 12

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(params string[] args) => new Program().run(args);

    class Circle
    {
        public PointF P;
        public float R;
    }

    class Line
    {
        public PointF S;
        public PointF E;
        public Circle C1;
        public Circle C2;
        public Line(Circle c1, Circle c2, PointF s, PointF e)
        {
            S = s;
            E = e;
            C1 = c1;
            C2 = c2;
        }
    }


    List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();
    List<Circle> circles = new List<Circle>();

    void run(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i += 3)
            addcircle(args[i], args[i + 1], args[i + 2]);
        circles.Sort((c1, c2) => c1.P.X.CompareTo(c2.P.X));


        int mx = (int)circles.Max(c => c.P.X + c.R) + 1;
        int my = (int)circles.Max(c => c.P.Y + c.R) + 1;



        for (int i = 0; i < circles.Count; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < circles.Count; j++)
            {
                var c1 = circles[i];
                var c2 = circles[j];

                var d = dist(c1.P, c2.P);
                var a = 1 / d * sqrt((-d + c1.R - c2.R) * (-d - c1.R + c2.R) * (-d + c1.R + c2.R) * (d + c1.R + c2.R));
                var x = (sqr(d) - sqr(c2.R) + sqr(c1.R)) / (2 * d);

                var ap = angle(c1.P, c2.P);
                var la = rotate(c1.P, new PointF(c1.P.X + x, c1.P.Y + a / 2), ap);
                var lb = rotate(c1.P, new PointF(c1.P.X + x, c1.P.Y - a / 2), ap);
                var l = new Line(c1, c2, la, lb);
                lines.Add(l);
            }
        foreach (Line l in lines)
            foreach (Line lo in lines)
            {
                if (l == lo) continue;
                var intersection = intersect(l, lo);

                if (intersection != null && online(intersection.Value, l) && online(intersection.Value, lo))
                {
                    foreach (Circle circle in circles)
                    {
                        if (l.C1 == circle || l.C2 == circle)
                            continue;
                        if (dist(intersection.Value, circle.P) >= circle.R)
                            continue;

                        if (dist(l.E, circle.P) < circle.R)
                            l.E = intersection.Value;

                        if (dist(l.S, circle.P) < circle.R)
                            l.S = intersection.Value;
                    }
                }
            }


        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(mx, my))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                foreach (var c in circles)
                    draw(g, c);


                for (int i = 0; i < circles.Count; i++)
                {
                    var c1 = circles[i];
                    var p = new PointF(c1.P.X + c1.R, c1.P.Y);
                    for (int j = 0; j < circles.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == j) continue;
                        var c2 = circles[j];
                        for (var f = 0f; f <= 360f; f += 0.1f)
                        {
                            var pl = rotate(c1.P, p, f);
                            if (dist(pl, c2.P) <= c2.R)
                            {
                                g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.White), (int)pl.X, (int)pl.Y, 1, 1);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }


                foreach (var l in lines)
                    draw(g, l);

            }
            bmp.Save("t.bmp");
        }
    }

    private float dist(PointF p1, PointF p2) => sqrt(sqr(p1.X - p2.X) + sqr(p1.Y - p2.Y));


    bool online(PointF p, Line l)
    {
        var lx = l.S.X < l.E.X ? l.S.X : l.E.X;
        var hx = l.S.X > l.E.X ? l.S.X : l.E.X;
        var ly = l.S.Y < l.E.Y ? l.S.Y : l.E.Y;
        var hy = l.S.Y > l.E.Y ? l.S.Y : l.E.Y;

        return p.X >= lx && p.X <= hx && p.Y >= ly && p.Y <= hy;
    }

    static PointF? intersect(Line l1, Line l2)
    {
        //Line1
        float A1 = l1.E.Y - l1.S.Y;
        float B1 = l1.S.X - l1.E.X;
        float C1 = A1 * l1.S.X + B1 * l1.S.Y;

        //Line2
        float A2 = l2.E.Y - l2.S.Y;
        float B2 = l2.S.X - l2.E.X;
        float C2 = A2 * l2.S.X + B2 * l2.S.Y;

        float det = A1 * B2 - A2 * B1;
        if (det == 0)
        {
            return null; //parallel lines
        }
        float x = (B2 * C1 - B1 * C2) / det;
        float y = (A1 * C2 - A2 * C1) / det;
        return new PointF(x, y);
    }

    void addcircle(string x, string y, string r)
    {
        var SCALE = 20f;
        Circle c1 = new Circle
        {
            P = new PointF(float.Parse(x) * SCALE, float.Parse(y) * SCALE),
            R = float.Parse(r) * SCALE
        };
        circles.Add(c1);
    }

    void draw(Graphics g, Line l) => g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), l.S.X, l.S.Y, l.E.X, l.E.Y);

    PointF rotate(PointF o, PointF p, float angle)
    {
        var sa = (float)Math.Sin(angle);
        var ca = (float)Math.Cos(angle);
        var dx = p.X - o.X;
        var dy = p.Y - o.Y;

        return new PointF((ca * dx - sa * dy + o.X), (sa * dx + ca * dy + o.Y));
    }

    float angle(PointF p1, PointF p2)
    {
        var dx = p2.X - p1.X;
        if (dx == 0)
            return 0f;
        return (float)Math.Atan((p2.Y - p1.Y) / dx);
    }


    void draw(Graphics g, Circle c)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Blue),
                      c.P.X - c.R,
                      c.P.Y - c.R,
                      c.R * 2,
                      c.R * 2);
    }

    float sqr(float d) => d * d;
    float sqrt(float d) => (float)Math.Sqrt(d);
}
```

All the Math involved here is based on [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html). The coordinates of the lines were easy to get using the formulars from the link. However they needed to be rotated by the angle between the two involved cricles centers.

To reduce the lines length i calculated their intersections. Then for that intersection i checked if the current lines end reaches into a circle that isnt the "parent of the line" and also contains the intersection itself. If that was the case, that end of the line was reduced to the location of the intersection.

The circles were simple to draw, the "notneeded" parts were difficult to remove, so i came up with a "rubber" solution, that removes the stuff that isnt needed anymore by painting it white again. Kind of brute forcing it. This is done by walking along each circles edge and checking if that pixel is within range of another circle.

Initially i wanted to roll my own circle-drawing method that only draws the circle withing specified angles but that didnt turn out well and took even more lines of code.

Really having a hard time explaining this if you havent noticed... English isnt my mother tounge so i am sorry for that.

Golfed

```
using System;using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Drawing;using System.Drawing.Imaging;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(params string[]args)=>new P().R(args);class C{public PointF P;public float R;}class L{public PointF S;public PointF E;public C C1;public C C2;public L(C c1,C c2,PointF s,PointF e){S=s;E=e;C1=c1;C2=c2;}}List<L>_=new List<L>();List<C>c=new List<C>();void R(string[]args){for(int i=0;i<args.Length;i+=3)A(args[i],args[i+1],args[i+2]);c.Sort((c1,c2)=>c1.P.X.CompareTo(c2.P.X));int B=(int)c.Max(c=>c.P.X+c.R)+1;int e=(int)c.Max(c=>c.P.Y+c.R)+1;for(int i=0;i++<c.Count;)for(int j=i+1;j++<c.Count;){var f=c[i];var q=c[j];var d=D(f.P,q.P);var a=1/d*S((-d+f.R-q.R)*(-d-f.R+q.R)*(-d+f.R+q.R)*(d+f.R+q.R));var x=(F(d)-F(q.R)+F(f.R))/(2*d);var h=angle(f.P,q.P);var k=R(f.P,new PointF(f.P.X+x,f.P.Y+a/2),h);var m=R(f.P,new PointF(f.P.X+x,f.P.Y-a/2),h);var l=new L(f,q,k,m);_.Add(l);}foreach(L l in _)foreach(L o in _){if(l==o)continue;var n=I(l,o);if(n !=null && O(n.Value,l)&& O(n.Value,o)){foreach(C p in c){if(l.C1==p || l.C2==p)continue;if(D(n.Value,p.P)>=p.R)continue;if(D(l.E,p.P)<p.R)l.E=n.Value;if(D(l.S,p.P)<p.R)l.S=n.Value;}}}Bitmap r=new Bitmap(B,e);Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage(r);g.Clear(Color.White);foreach(var _ in c)D(g,_);for(int i=0;i++<c.Count;){var Q=c[i];var P=new PointF(Q.P.X+Q.R,Q.P.Y);for(int j=0;j++<c.Count;){if(i==j)continue;var G=c[j];for(var f=0f;f<=360f;f+=0.1f){var H=R(Q.P,P,f);if(D(H,G.P)<=G.R){g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.White),(int)H.X,(int)H.Y,1,1);}}}}foreach(var l in _)D(g,l);r.Save("t.bmp");}float D(PointF p1,PointF p2)=>S(F(p1.X-p2.X)+F(p1.Y-p2.Y));bool O(PointF p,L l){var lx=l.S.X<l.E.X ? l.S.X : l.E.X;var hx=l.S.X>l.E.X ? l.S.X : l.E.X;var ly=l.S.Y<l.E.Y ? l.S.Y : l.E.Y;var hy=l.S.Y>l.E.Y ? l.S.Y : l.E.Y;return p.X>=lx && p.X<=hx && p.Y>=ly && p.Y<=hy;}static PointF? I(L l1,L l2){float a=l1.E.Y-l1.S.Y;float b=l1.S.X-l1.E.X;float d=a*l1.S.X+b*l1.S.Y;float e=l2.E.Y-l2.S.Y;float f=l2.S.X-l2.E.X;float g=e*l2.S.X+f*l2.S.Y;float h=a*f-e*b;if(h==0)return null;float x=(f*d-b*g)/h;float y=(a*g-e*d)/h;return new PointF(x,y);}void A(string x,string y,string r){var F=20f;C _=new C{P=new PointF(float.Parse(x)*F,float.Parse(y)*F),R=float.Parse(r)*F };c.Add(_);}void D(Graphics g,L l)=>g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red),l.S.X,l.S.Y,l.E.X,l.E.Y);PointF R(PointF o,PointF p,float angle){var a=(float)Math.Sin(angle);var n=(float)Math.Cos(angle);var b=p.X-o.X;var x=p.Y-o.Y;return new PointF((n*b-a*x+o.X),(a*b+n*x+o.Y));}float angle(PointF p1,PointF p2){var a=p2.X-p1.X;if(a==0)return 0f;return(float)Math.Atan((p2.Y-p1.Y)/a);}void D(Graphics g,C c){g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Blue),c.P.X-c.R,c.P.Y-c.R,c.R*2,c.R*2);}float F(float d)=>d*d;float S(float d)=>(float)Math.Sqrt(d);}
```

[image: Result1]
[image: Result2]

More Complex examples (top circle gets into negative y values)

[image: Result3]
[image: No rubber]